# What's caused my Firefox background to change suddenly?

Tags: firefox

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4, and I didn't make any changes to my Firefox settings. A couple of days ago,  my Firefox began rendering webpages using a "minimalist background" ([see example of how it renders the StackOverflow homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKDjg.jpg)) that is hard on the eyes and makes some sites unusable.

I have not been able to find a discussion of this issue online. Has anyone else experienced this problem? Is there a simple solution to revert the browser to a factory default or previous settings? I have tried restarting Firefox in safe mode, but the issue was not resolved even then.

Comment: I have an Ubuntu 18.04.4 virtual machine here with Firefox 73.0 running. It looks fine and normal to me. Pretty much the same as Firefox 68 running in Kali here. Are you able to update or repair the video driver on your host machine?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling firefox?

Comment: Have you installed an add-on called [No Color](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/no-color/) which turns off all images and colours from the rendered page? I use it and it has exactly the effect you describe.

Comment: 1. I googled a bit and could not figure out how to update or repair the video driver though I would be willing to try this with instructions. It seems that the driver is not the problem, as Firefox is the only application impacted. 2. I uninstalled and reinstalled, and the problem still persists. 3. I checked my extensions and did not see anything in the section above “recommended extensions”.